# Error while importing SVGs

Tags: import, error, svg

I have the .svg addon enabled and wanted to import such files into Blender. Some files import normally, others display an error, like such:

[image]

Here is the code for the SVG that imported just fine:

```
<svg width="22" height="22" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M21 13.143h-7.857V21H8.857v-7.857H1V8.857h7.857V1h4.286v7.857H21v4.286z" fill="#19BA4E"/></svg>
```

and here is the code for the SVG that's causing error:

```
<svg width="24" height="24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M14.302 11.79h5.024L7.403 19.74A9 9 0 0017.686 5.023l-3.384 6.767zm1.72-7.843L4.256 11.79h5.023l-3.402 6.805a9 9 0 0110.145-14.65z" fill="#00D7FF"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I uploaded the SVG files to this program: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ and cleaned them up using the default settings. Blender now imports them just fine.